# Update shopify inventory automatically

Tags: json, api, shopify, backend, e-commerce

I have a shopify website, but my fulfilment process is done outside of shopify, meaning that when the customer picks a product, it redirects to another service, were the fulfillment is done, and the the purchase is concluded. Because of that, shopify has no way to know if the purchase is concluded or not, so the store has to be updated manually. This is what I would like to avoid.Is is there an app, or a way I can update shopify by sending a json or a CSV with the updated products? And does uploading a CSV with the entirety of my data to repopulate my inventory a valid idea?

I expect there to be an outside service/App that might be able to help automate this, because I am able to receive a Json file (via an api) with all the info of the products that have been purchased, but I don't know how to use it to update shopify.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you fulfill external to Shopify with a service, Shopify can be set to maintain your inventory by removing the sold inventory. Fulfillment does not really come into play.

Regardless though, Shopify does have an API, and there are handy calls that let you update 100 SKUs with a new quantity, in one API call, at one location. So if you have a CSV or JSON file, it is very easy to use that data to update Shopify. Make authenticated API calls. In the store itself, you can generate a token allowing API updates, and you can test with Postman, meaning your total investment in this is near zero.